# Close and minimize button behavior for my desktop application

Tags: desktop-application, windows-os

I am developing a desktop application that will run on user's PC in background(system tray). User won't have to start the app as it starts with the system. Basically this app listens to a port and waiting for http request. Users will be able to change the port(rare case) by clicking the application's system tray icon. Here is the screenshot:

[image]

I don't want the users to close the app accidentally. Should I use the close button as minimize to system tray or the minimize button itself?

**Edit:** Users can quit the app by system tray icon's menu. Like: Skype.

**n.b.** I disabled the maximize button as the window size is fixed.

Comment: Excellent question.  I've seen applications use various approaches with this and I generally don't know what to expect as a user.

Comment: Does closing the app cancel the process? Or does it still run in the background as normal?

Answer (score 1):

I uses to dislike applications that "unexpectedly" continued to run after you clicked "close", but *in this instance*, I don't think this is the case and that adding a "*Minimise to tray*" icon would be the wrong approach. My reasoning:

- From the description, your "real application" is a service (or an auto-starting process) that sits in the background doing it's job (listening for incoming requests).
- While running, it displays an icon in the system tray that **(a)** shows the user it is running, **(b)** allows them to stop it, and **(c)** allows them to change the configuration.
- The GUI you've shown *isn't your real application*. It's simply a screen where you can configure it's operation. As such, closing *that window* (using the normal "**X**" icon) should not affect the main [background] application.
- However, because users may not be fully aware that the screen shown is simply a configuration tool, *the first time* they click the "**X**" icon, you may want to show a message informing them that the application will continue to run in the background.
- Because of the above, you *may* want to remove/disable the minimise icon (as you've done for the maximise icon), although there's probably no harm in leaving it doing what it currently does (using this button *wouldn't* give the above warning).
- Finally, if you feel "*stopping the [background] application*" is going to be a sufficiently common task, you *may* want to add a normal, in-window button to the configuration screen (e.g. "*Terminate XYZZY Listener*") as well as the option that's on the system-tray icon.

Answer (score 0):

I would do the following:

1. Add a prompt when the user presses the close (`X`) button that asks them something along the lines of "Are you sure you want to exit?"
2. Disable/Remove the minimize and maximize buttons
3. Add a "Minimize to Tray" icon instead, the one that looks like an arrow pointing to the lower-right hand corner.  Like in this image:

[image: Minimize to tray]

Answer (score 0):

Remove the minimize and maximize buttons so there is only the close button. And then use the window as a form of dialog window because its only used for such a simple task. Maybe add a close button at the bottom.